# How to diagnose "docker: invalid reference format" when calling "docker run"?

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I'm trying to create a shell script to run a docker container and am struggling. My script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    echo "Usage > run.sh IMAGE NAME"
    echo
    echo "i.e. ./build.sh cd2:0.0.49"
    exit
fi

echo $1

docker run -it --rm \
-e NODE_PATH='./src'\
-e NODE_HOST='0.0.0.0'\
-e NODE_ENV='production'\
-e DOCKER=true\
-e PORT='8080'\
-e STAGING=true\
-e SENDGRID_API_KEY='<redacted>'\
-p 8080:8080 $1
```

When I run: `bash run.sh cd2:0.0.50`

I get: `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.`

Even if I do `bash run.sh cd:0.0.50` it still fails (`echo $1` results in `cd2:0.0.50`).

If I run `docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 cd2:0.0.50` from the command line it works...

Can anyone help?

Comment: I would suggest that it isn't parsing the -e flags correctly and seeing the NOD_PATH variable as the image name. What happens when you take the -e data out?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Hmmm, it works...

Comment: You just need to re-arrange you docker run command. I've posted an answer

Comment: Not a solution to this problem, but you would also see this error if you set a variable in the script, `FOO="joe foo bar"`, and then reference it in the docker command like this, `-e FOO=$FOO`. The error will arise due to the spaces. You would need to quote the value, `-e FOO="$FOO"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The image name should be immediately after the `-it` options.
Move the `-it` options to the end:

```
docker run \
-e NODE_PATH='./src' \
-e NODE_HOST='0.0.0.0' \
-e NODE_ENV='production' \
-e DOCKER=true \
-e PORT='8080' \
-e STAGING=true \
-e SENDGRID_API_KEY='<redacted>' \
-p 8080:8080 --rm -it $1
```

Comment: I've amended the answer

Comment: What's wrong with `docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -p 5555:5555 \ -e SAUCE_USERNAME -e SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY \ -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos \ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ dosel/zalenium start --sauceLabsEnabled true` ? It is also giving same error.

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces after the `\\`.