# docker command transferred from Mac to Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to use docker in windows 10 pro. I used it in Mac before. When I try to use the command below, error message was popped up.

Please help.

Command line:

> docker run -v db_car_my-db-1:/dbdata -v $(pwd)/backups:/backup --rm ubuntu tar xvf /backup/db_data_19-03-11.tar -C /dbdata --strip 1

Error Message:

> C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\db_car\db_car> docker run -v db_car_my-db-1:/dbdata -v $(pwd)/backups:/backup --rm ubuntu t
>   ar xvf /backup/db_data_19-03-11.tar -C /dbdata --strip 1
>   C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.
>   See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `$(pwd)`. If you are running this command on the powershell you should use curly brackets:

`docker run -v db_car_my-db-1:/dbdata -v ${pwd}/backups:/backup --rm ubuntu tar xvf /backup/db_data_19-03-11.tar -C /dbdata --strip 1`

(see also [docker : invalid reference format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682010/docker-invalid-reference-format))