# Why do I get 'docker: invalid reference format' when trying to turn my image into a container?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

Want to use 'docker run' to create a container from an image id, using --privileged and mounting 3 volumes. This never seems to work when I try it and I frequently get 'invalid reference format'.

Although none of these containers show up when I run 'sudo docker container ls', a few show up when I run 'sudo docker container ls -a'

List of commands I've tried:

```
sudo docker run 24d052d7a24e  --priveleges -t \ -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys

sudo docker run --priveleges -t \ -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys 24d052d7a24e

sudo docker run --privileged -t \ -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys 24d052d7a24e

sudo docker run --privileged -t \ -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys \ 24d052d7a24e

sudo docker run --privileged -t -v /dev:/dev -v /proc:/proc -v /sys:/sys 24d052d7a24e

sudo docker run --privileged -t -v /dev:/dev -v /proc:/proc -v /sys:/sys 24d052d7a24e ubuntu

sudo docker run --name milanlakhani/l4tar --privileged -t -v /dev:/dev -v /proc:/proc -v /sys:/sys 24d052d7a24e

sudo docker run --privileged -t \ -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys \ 24d052d7a24e /bin/bash

sudo docker run --privileged -t -v /dev:/dev -v /proc:/proc -v /sys:/sys 24d052d7a24e /bin/bash

sudo docker run --privileged -t \ -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys \ 24d052d7a24e /bin/bash

sudo docker run --name milan-test --privileged -t \ -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys \ 24d052d7a24e /bin/bash

sudo docker run --name 'milan-test' --privileged -t \ -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys \ 24d052d7a24e /bin/bash

sudo docker run --name 'milan-test' --privileged -t -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys \ 24d052d7a24e /bin/bash

sudo docker run --privileged -t \ -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys \ 24d052d7a24e /bin/bash

sudo docker run --privileged -t \ -v /dev:/dev \ -v /proc:/proc \ -v /sys:/sys \ '24d052d7a24e' /bin/bash

sudo docker run -t \ -v "/dev:/dev" \ -v "/proc:/proc" \ -v "/sys:/sys" \ 24d052d7a24e /bin/bash

sudo docker run --privileged -t -v /dev:/dev -v /proc:/proc -v /sys:/sys '24d052d7a24e' /bin/bash

sudo docker run -t -v /dev:/dev -v /proc:/proc -v /sys:/sys --privileged '24d052d7a24e' /bin/bash

sudo docker run --name 'milan-test' 24d052d7a24e /bin/bash

sudo docker run --name 'milan-test' 24d052d7a24e

sudo docker run --name 'milan-test' 24d052d7a24e /bin/bash
```

Comment: Check: [What does "invalid reference format" mean?](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2018/faq-stackoverflow-lightning.html#29) by [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch). Also, related question here: [docker : invalid reference format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682010/docker-invalid-reference-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to overwrite the containers /proc :

docker run -it -v /dev:/dev -v /sys:/sys -v /proc:/host/proc  --privileged  ubuntu bash