# Cannot specify current directory with docker run -v

Tags: powershell, docker

I am trying to execute the following docker command in PowerShell but I cannot get it to recognize the `$(PWD)` for the current directory. Help please.

```
docker run -it -v $(PWD):/app --workdir /app samgentile\aspnetcore
```

I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Comment: Can you remove the parentheses? $(PWD) -> "$PWD"

Comment: That still gives me the same error

Comment: In that case I suspect that is not the problem. If you run it without "-v ..." does it give the same error?

Comment: I need the volume mount but even without I get the same eror on  docker run -d -p 8080:5000 samgentile\aspnetcore

Comment: So it is the "\" in the image name. I think it is "samgentile/aspnetcore". Can you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [docker : invalid reference format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51208726/596285)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "/" instead of "\" in the image name:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/app --workdir /app samgentile/aspnetcore
```

Answer (score 0):

Mihai is correct to point out the parentheses. These signify that you want to run the command `PWD` and use its output, whereas without the parentheses `PWD` is considered a variable. A correct invocation would take the form:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/app --workdir /app samgentile/aspnetcore
```

Or:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/app --workdir /app samgentile/aspnetcore
```

Comment: This is not really an answer, it's more like a comment. See See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @michalhosna well the question isn't really a question its more like demand

Comment: @CameronNemo If you don't like the question, then you shouldn't be answering it. You can always comment, flag, and all of that. But answering to question, you don't think is good, isn't the best way. Don't get me wrong, answering is the most important thing on SO, but quantity is not enough without quality.