# Issue running project using docker

Tags: windows, docker

I am trying to install docker in my windows machine and run the project with given command.

```
docker run -it -p 8000:80 --rm -v "$PWD":/var/www/html registry.XXXXXX/docker-images/legacy-admin:master
```

I am running windows so instead of `$PWD`, I used `D:/projects/`

But I am getting the following error

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'
```

Comment: are you running it from cmd or powershell or what?

Comment: i am using powershell

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682010/docker-invalid-reference-format)

Comment: @michalk I tried docker run -it -p 8000:80 --rm -v %cd d%: /projects registry....... didnot worked

Comment: try `docker run -it -p 8000:80 --rm -v ${PWD}:/var/www/html registry.XXXXXX/docker-images/legacy-admin:master`

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -it -d -p 8000:80 --rm -v "$PWD":/var/www/html registry.XXXXXX/docker-images/legacy-admin:maste
```

Try running above lines

Comment: $PWD env var supports in windows?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.