# Docker invalid reference when using $(pwd) mac os

Tags: docker, appium

//Runs android sdk on container

```
docker run -it — rm -v $(pwd)/sdk:/sdk thyrlian/android-sdk bash -c 'cp -a $ANDROID_HOME/. /sdk'
```

Throws below error

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: does your pwd has space in it ?

Comment: no space in $(pwd)

Comment: Whether any of the solutions discussed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682010/docker-invalid-reference-format helps ?

Comment: tried them as well didnt help :(

Comment: can u help me how to find static value for $(pwd) ?

Comment: If I am understanding it right, you want to get the value of pwd. you can simply use `echo $pwd`.

Comment: 1. Can you please confirm that the image is contained in the path mentioned above, you can try `echo $(pwd)/sdk:/sdk thyrlian/android-sdk`
2. Also see whether the `ANDROID_HOME` variable contains the correct value.
3. The `/sdk` folder is present in your system ?

Comment: Whether the path is correct? Use `echo "$(pwd)/sdk:/sdk thyrlian/android-sdk"`
1. do you have : in the name of the folder ?
2. Also do you have folder with name `sdk thyrlian`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205141/discussion-between-deepak-patankar-and-baala).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the exact command you need to run in the interactive terminal?

In your case,

"- rm" is incorrect, there should no space between - and rm, so it should be -rm

Secondly, it should be --rm and re try.

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/sdk:/sdk thyrlian/android-sdk bash -c 'cp -a $ANDROID_HOME/. /sdk'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking too far in the command for the error. In this case it's earlier. In this command:

```
docker run -it — rm -v $(pwd)/sdk:/sdk thyrlian/android-sdk bash -c 'cp -a $ANDROID_HOME/. /sdk'
```

The invalid image name is the long dash: `—`. The `rm` needs two normal dashes (since it's not a single character style arg like the `-i` and `-t`). Those are dashes that you'd type with the keyboard, and some editor that you've likely copy and pasted from converted that. The correct command is:

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd)/sdk:/sdk" thyrlian/android-sdk bash -c 'cp -a $ANDROID_HOME/. /sdk'
```

Note, you should always quote the path since it can contain a space that would also break the parsing of the args.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens when the docker image name given in the command is invalid. Please try this command

```
docker run -it — rm -v "$(pwd)/sdk:/sdk thyrlian/android-sdk" bash -c 'cp -a $ANDROID_HOME/. /sdk'
```