# Docker volume mapping folder issue on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to run the following command

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v/app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app 2ef0206fcf99
```

I am getting the following error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create $(pwd): "$(pwd)" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: One alternative approach is to swap to Docker Compose, even if you have only one container. You can use relative volumes there, e.g. `-v .:/app`, even on Windows.

Comment: What is the value of `$(pwd)` if you run that in your console? (Maybe edit the question and add that.) Then compare that to the regex it shows in the error. Does it return an error because your running it in a cmd window instead of Powershell (`pwd` doesn't exist in cmd but does in Powershell because it's an alias to `Get-Location`)? Do you _actually have_ illegal characters in your path? Etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker : invalid reference format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682010/docker-invalid-reference-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Using `Windows Powershell`, following works for me:

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${pwd}:/mydir nginx:latest bash
```

Note:

- I have used curly braces around `pwd` instead of small braces

2) Using `Git Bash`, following syntax should work:

```
winpty docker run --rm -it -v "/$PWD":/mydir nginx:latest bash
```

Note:

- If you do not use `winpty` at the start of the command, you will get error message: `the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'`
- Also notice the `/` before `$PWD`. Without the `/`, it will not throw error but i noticed that it didn't mount the directory.

Comment: Note that `$(pwd)` is also valid in Powershell, though stylistically I too prefer `{}`.

Comment: @msanford: If i use `$(pwd)`, i get error: `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format`

Comment: @Technext $(pwd) worked for me too on windows powershell !!

Comment: Interesting! Reading more I discovered this is actually a dupe. Odd dockerism perhaps? You get a +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue on windows make sure that you put "$PWD" something like this so your command should be something like this

```
docker run --rm -it -p 3000:3000 -v "$PWD:/app" 2ef0206fcf99
```

or another way is

```
docker run --rm -it -p 3000:3000 --volume="$PWD:/app" 2ef0206fcf99
```

Comment: I see that it's not mounting the directory when i tried your syntax

Comment: @Technext I have added correct version. Please check now