# docker: invalid reference format while using environment variables

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to run the following command within a script and keep getting the following error

> docker: invalid reference format.

I also tried running the cmd without quotes around the env variable names and also without $ and { , same result.

```
sudo docker run --name "${container_name}-${number}" --cpus="${cpus_per_container}" \
--cpuset-cpus="${cpu_1}","${cpu_2}" \
--restart always -e VIRTUAL_HOST="${virtual_host}" \
-e NODE_ENV="${environment}" -d "${container_registry}:${tag_name}"
```

Anything that should be changed in the above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker : invalid reference format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682010/docker-invalid-reference-format)

Comment: Probably better to add `$USER` to docker group vs running with `sudo`.

Comment: Are all of those shell variables set?  Put the word `echo` at the front of the command and run it; what's the command line it prints out?

Comment: (Since it's pretty trivial to use `docker run` to root the host, it's appropriate to require `sudo` access for it.)

Comment: @DavidMaze - docker should never be used in production because of the risk you mention, however, docker is a dev tool and it's much better to put the developer in the docker group on their local machines for their convenience.

Comment: yup was an env variables that wasn't getting transferred correctly from another place, that got it working, also switched to docker run by adding $USER to the group, thanks!