# I want to bind mount tomcat server to my local machine

Tags: devops

I tried below command

```
docker run -it -d -p 8888:8080 -v /users/vaibhav pund/desktop:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps tomcat
```

but throws an error:

```
invalid reference format
```

Tried multiple times. Please reply me

Answer (score 0):

try:
docker run -it -d -p 8888:8080 -v ***"/users/vaibhav pund/desktop"***:***"/usr/local/tomcat/webapps tomcat"***

because of space in your directory path.

Consult their image description also:
https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67855579/10744181