# Docker run command returns "invalid reference format"

Tags: docker

I'm using docker on Windows and typed following command on powershell to get container:

```
docker run -v C:\Users\inter\Documents\work:\work -p 8888:8888 --name my-env datascientistus\ds-python-env
```

Although I could pull docker image from docker hub successfully, I got "invalid reference format" error.

I coundn't understand what's wrong with this command.

Any idea really appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image name is:

```
datascientistus/ds-python-env
```

not

```
datascientistus\ds-python-env
```

Backslashes are not valid in an image name.

For others running into this issue, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45682010/596285) for a more complete answer.