# Why does is it have an invalid format?

Tags: javascript, cypress

`docker run -it -v "%cd%":/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:6.2.1 --browser chrome`

If try to run this command in Visual Studio Code it throws me an error like this:

`docker: invalid reference format. See 'docker run --help'`

I tried to change "%cd%" in {pwd} or $PWD , I´m using Windows and I think "%cd%" is the best way but it didn´t work.

Comment: Did you try `-v "%cd%:/e2e"`?

Comment: You could also consider to use PowerShell, then you can use `${pwd}`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51379726/5470544

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `${PWD}` instead of `%cd%`

```
docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:6.2.1 --browser chrome
```