# docker: invalid reference format using kong command

Tags: docker, command, kong-plugin

I am running below docker command in Command Prompt, but I am getting "docker: invalid reference format." this error.

```
docker run -d --name kong-dbless \
--network=kong-net \
-v "$(pwd):/kong/declarative/" \
-e "KONG_DATABASE=off" \
-e "KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=/kong/declarative/kong.yml" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_GUI_URL=http://localhost:8002" \
-e KONG_LICENSE_DATA \
-p 8000:8000 \
-p 8443:8443 \
-p 8001:8001 \
-p 8444:8444 \
-p 8002:8002 \
-p 8445:8445 \
-p 8003:8003 \
-p 8004:8004 \
kong/kong-gateway:3.6.1.1
```

Please anyone help on this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker : invalid reference format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682010/docker-invalid-reference-format)