# Docker & Zalenium: Unable to start due to invalid reference format error

Tags: docker, cmd, zalenium

Really new to docker and docker infrastructure. So from the official [Zalenium github page](https://github.com/zalando/zalenium) I followed all the steps successfully until I get to the point:

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 \
           -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
           -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos \
           --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```

and after executing it I'm getting:

```
> docker: invalid reference format. 
> See 'docker run --help'
```

While doing research here on SOF, I've landed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682010/docker-invalid-reference-format) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280858/docker-invalid-reference-format-in-shell-script), but nothing seems to work in my situation. I've tried to replace `--rm -ti` to the end of the expression: didn't work

```
docker run --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 \
           -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
           -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos \
           --privileged --rm -ti dosel/zalenium start
```

I'm sure there is a specific format that I have to follow, but can't find a clue to it (missing comma, wrong backslash, unnecessary whitespace). Appreciate for your help.

Comment: On which OS are you running this?

Comment: @TarunLalwani This is Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: This error usually occurs when docker is not happy about one of the parameters. Can you start with `docker run --name zalenium dosel/zalenium start` and starting adding parameters one by one to see which one is actually causing the problem

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've figured the problem. I just omitted all backslashes ( \ ) at the initial run command and zalenium started successfully. I'm not sure what they indicate in the example? New line?

Comment: they are if you type command in multiple lines

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that the command example we have does not work for Windows, I just changed the docs to show how to run a multiline command in Windows.

Here is the way:

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 ^
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ^
  -v /c/Users/your_user_name/temp/videos:/home/seluser/videos ^
  --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```