# docker saucelabs : invalid reference format

Tags: docker, saucelabs, zalenium

I have gone through this article http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-disposable-selenium-grid-infrastructure-setup-using-zalenium **Integrating with Cloud Testing Platforms:**

I have already added sauce username and access key in Environment variables. It `docker`, `Zalenium` works without `Saucelabs` but with saucelabs gives error: `docker.exe: invalid reference format.`

**Without Saucelabs - works fine:**

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
-v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start
```

**With Saucelabs - gives formatting error:**

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -p 5555:5555 \ 
-e SAUCE_USERNAME 
-e SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY \ 
-v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos \ 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ dosel/zalenium start --sauceLabsEnabled true
```

I am using `Docker Toolbox` on Windows 7

Already took reference of:

1. [docker: invalid reference format in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280858/docker-invalid-reference-format-in-shell-script)
2. [docker : invalid reference format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682010/docker-invalid-reference-format)
3. [Docker command returns "invalid reference format"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435418/docker-command-returns-invalid-reference-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was - I was using back slash `\`. After removing it from command it worked. After removing it becomes

```
docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -p 5555:5555
-e SAUCE_USERNAME
-e SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY
-v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock dosel/zalenium start --sauceLabsEnabled true
```

Take care of unnecessary space also.

Comment: Exactly, the ```\``` is valid only in *nix operating systems. For Windows, you could use `^` or ` (backtick), I think it depends if you use PowerShell or the conventional terminal.