# Problem trying to running Guacamole with Docker

Tags: docker, guacamole

I'm following this youtube tutorial. I have everything working fine until minute 8:00 when the video author copy and paste this command:

```
docker run --name guacamole --link guacd:guacd --link guac-mysql:mysql \ -e MYSQL_DATABASE='guacamole' \ -e MYSQL_USER='guacamole' \ -e MYSQL_PASSWORD='sqlpassword' \ -d -p 8080:8080 guacamole/guacamole
```

After it I'm having the annoying:

> docker: invalid reference format.
>   see 'docker run --help'

I have tried other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682010/docker-invalid-reference-format) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280858/docker-invalid-reference-format-in-shell-script/45281200#45281200)

Please, if someone knows how to overcome this problem give me help.

Thx!

Comment: Do you mean for there to be line breaks after the \?

Comment: yes, they're line breaks

Comment: Sometimes it says "docker: invalid reference format. repository name must be lowercase" as well

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Spacing was the problem.

I used

```
docker run --name guacamole^
  --link guacd:guacd^
  --link guac-mysql:mysql^
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE='guacamole'^
  -e MYSQL_USER='guacamole'^
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD='sqlpassword'^
  -d -p 8080:8080 guacamole/guacamole
```

where (^) is my line breaker.